# SAS: Translate code from proc SQL, regarding counter of distinct pair of variables from a dataset

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I want to get the same results with **SAS code**, as I did with **proc SQL**. I have junior level knowledge on **SAS code**, so any assistance would be nice. Thanks in advance for your time.

my target is the following **table**:

```
id  counter
1   3
2   2
3   3
```

```
data example1;
input id x y $ k z;
cards;
1 2 A 1 60
1 6 B 2 70
1 2 C 3 100
2 2 B 2 10
2 3 C 3 67
3 2 A 1 81
3 3 B 2 63
3 5 F 6 55
;
run;

proc sql;
  select id, count(distinct put(id,best12.)||put(k,best12.)) AS counter
    from example1
    group by id;
quit;
```

I tried **proc freq**, **proc sort** but didn't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run two `Proc FREQ` steps.

```
data have;
input id x y $ k z;
cards;
1 2 A 1 60
1 6 B 2 70
1 2 C 3 100
2 2 B 2 10
2 3 C 3 67
3 2 A 1 81
3 3 B 2 63
3 5 F 6 55
3 6 G 6 55
3 7 H 6 55
3 8 I 7 55
3 9 J 7 55
3 0 K 1 55
;
run;

proc freq noprint data=have ;
  table id*k / out=freq1;
run;
proc freq noprint data=freq1;
  table id / out=want (keep=id count);
run;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, didn't think of using two times in row, proc freq!